# Batch script Moving %%var to string variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read the file `print.txt` which is having file paths

example: `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\a1.jpg`

It getw read successfully, but when I am trying to move it to filename var its not getting any value. The echo prints as `'filename is: filename`

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%s in (print.txt) do ( 
Set filename=" " %%s " "
echo.filename is: %filename
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%s in (print.lst) do ( 
echo %%s
Set filename=%%s
echo filename is: "!filename!"
)
```

#### Update 2

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%s in (print.lst) do ( 
echo %%s
Set filename=%%s
echo filename is: "!filename!"
For %%A in (!filename!) do ( 
 Set Folder=%%~dpA 
 Set Name=%%~nxA 
 echo.Folder is: !Folder! 
 )
)
```

Comment: What does your file have? single line? or multiple lines of urls?

Comment: Multiple lines of url's 1 url per line example:
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\1431309.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\a1.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\a2.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\a3.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Pictures\a4.jpg

Comment: yes..Tried saved the file with Print.Lst extension and ran the script but still same issue

Comment: Hey it worked..but now facing next problem not able to get folder name split echo.filename is: !filename!

For %%A in (%filename%) do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set Name=%%~nxA
    echo.Folder is: %Folder%
)

Comment: Sorry but now the its not going in second for loop. For %%A in (%filename%) do ( ...Not printing the echo.Folder is:<folder name>. Please help he for this and I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Use !filename! instead of %filename%

Comment: The code works for me... It should work for you too... Let me know,.